# APC cache shared between different directories?

Tags: php, caching, apc

I'm working on a PHP project in a team. The team members have their own working directory on a CentOS/apache server, like this.

```
/home/user1/public_html/project/xxxxx.php
/home/user2/public_html/project/xxxxx.php
```

and so on. 
We write and upload php files there and test our work by accessing the server from a browser.

The problem is that APC caches those php files without distinguishing their directories. So, after accessing user1/project/xxxxx.php, it is cached, then accessing user2/project/xxxxx.php produces a result from user1's php.

I think this is because APC shares cache between different processes and/or paths. Is there any way to turn this feature off? For some reason we cannot simply turn off APC, we need it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the APC cache. You can use PHP's built-in function [`apc_clear_cache(`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-clear-cache.php) to clear the system cache.

There's also `apc_clear_cache('user')`. Calling that will clear the user cache.

Hope that helps!